# Component in JScrollView in GridBagLayout drawn too small

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I've got a custom component, derived from `JComponent`. I'm placing that into a `JScrollPane` and that into a container using `GridBagLayout`. Now if the container gets too small, i.e. has to start displaying scroll bars, the component becomes *tiny*.

The example below renders as follows after starting the application:

[image: Initial view]

But after resizing the frame a bit, it becomes this:

[image: Resized view]

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class SO26736343 extends JPanel {
    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container cp = frm.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        cp.add(new JButton("NW"), gbc);
        cp.add(new JButton("N"), gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        cp.add(new JButton("NE"), gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        cp.add(new JButton("W"), gbc);
        cp.add(new JScrollPane(new SO26736343()));
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        cp.add(new JButton("E"), gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        cp.add(new JButton("SW"), gbc);
        cp.add(new JButton("S"), gbc);
        cp.add(new JButton("SE"), gbc);
        frm.setSize(500, 500);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I executed this on OS X 10.8.5 with Java 1.7.0_25.

I guess there might be something wrong with my component, but I don't know what. Shouldn't the layout make an attempt to display that component as large as possible, even if it can't be displayed at its preferred size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to set the constraints when you are adding your custom panel and thus the behavior is unpredictable (or at least unexpected):

```
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    cp.add(new JButton("W"), gbc);
    cp.add(new JScrollPane(new SO26736343())); // gbc missing here
```

If you want this panel fill all available space, then set both `weightx` and `weighty` properties to a value greather than 0 and add your panel using this constraint:

```
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    cp.add(new JScrollPane(new SO26736343()), gbc);
```

#### Screenshots

[image: Normal]

[image: Shrunken]

Comment: That does fix my example. Unfortunately, the example was based on a real world application where I saw the same behavior, but there I *had* included that constraints object. Strange. OK, I guess I'll have to come up with a better reproducing example, which demonstrates the problem even if the constraints object is used. But I'll do that in a separate post.

Comment: You are welcome. I'll be waiting for that example @MvG

Comment: It seems that in my other example, the `weighty` was the problem. Again by overlooking something. So your answer applied after all, in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem happens a lot when I use textfields in Swing. I always set the minimum size of the problem component to its preferred size :

```
myComponent.setMinimumSize(myComponent.getPreferredSize());
```

You can also set weight and fill on the gbc.

```
////////////
gbc.weightx = 1.0;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
////////////
```

This prevents, when the scrollbars kick in, the collapsing effect. Most commonly happens in textfields and text areas.

http://blue-walrus.com/2011/04/swing-textfieldtextarea-collapse-on-dialog-resize/